# How to align center item in an Action bar on Android

Tags: java, android

i got an action bar with 3 menu items, sadly those are aligned on the left and i would have aligned in center. I've been looking around and tried some stuff but nothing is working.

Here's my code so far :

```
public class Layout extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.actionbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // action with ID action_refresh was selected
        case R.id.action_refresh:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Refresh selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            break;
        // action with ID action_settings was selected
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

}
```

and here's my R.layout.action :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="my Title"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are not really supposed to center-align the Text in the ActionBar (or Toolbar, depending on which you are using) - which is why it is not simpler to do.

If you leave it aligned like it should be currently, it should align with the 72dp keyline (which will match general Material Guidelines).

You will find those specifications here: https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar  (but again, if you do nothing, everything should work correctly)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Sadly this doesnt really help to solve my issues, this might no be the right way to do it, but this is something i've seen a lot in android app. Maybe the actionBar is not the appropriated component to use in my situation, if yes, which one would be ?

Comment: Well using something other then an ActionBar will be very difficult (there is a lot of functionality built into an ActionBar that you will have to duplicate).  Also just because you have seen another app do this, doesn't mean it was easy (or again, that it SHOULD be done)

Answer (score 0):

See, you may have seen some of the apps having centered text on action bar (toolbar), but the layout must be customized or with basic coding the API should be >5.0 to achieve such scenario.